# able to run rails server from production server directly but not pulling website from domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, dns, server

able to run rails server from production server directly but not pulling website from domain name,

I have an rails app which is deployed on EC2 instance with `unicorn+nginx`, both the things are running.

If I run `rails s RAILS_ENV=production`, it runs properly on ip address:3000, but when I enter hostname www.example.com, it shows `error 522 connection timeout`

Any help on this, I tried googling but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

**This may work**

```
rails s -e production -b your_host_ip -p 80
```

**OR**

```
rails s -e production -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

**OR**

```
 rails s -e production -b domain -p 80
```